# getDate() do Javascript retornando NULL

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, funções

```
(function(){
    var data = new Date();
    var dia = document.querySelector('.table tbody tr > td');
    dia.textContent = data.getDate();
})();
```

Tenho essa função no Javascript. Ela sempre retorna NULL.
Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: O que é que retorna null?

Comment: como disse na resposta verifica se o "caminho" do selector esta correto

Comment: Solucionei o problema.... Eu estava jogando o JS em cima do HTML.
Ou seja: Sempre seria NULL porque ele lia primeiro o JS. Desculpe a noobeira, galera. \=

Answer (score 1):

Simulei seu codigo aqui e esta funcionando normal. Ve se o seletor nao esta errado.

```js
(function(){
    var data = new Date();
    var dia = document.querySelector('.table tbody tr > td');
    dia.textContent = data.getDate();
})();
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data vem aqui</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Atualizei a tua função para retornar a Data dentro de um elemento com ID, mas tu pode usar o querySelector se for o caso:

```js
$(function() {
    var data = new Date();
    var dia = document.querySelector('#aqui');
    var mes = data.getMonth()+1; // Janeiro é 0!
    if(mes < 10) mes = '0'+mes;
    var ano = data.getFullYear();
    dia.innerHTML = data.getDate() + '/' + mes + '/' + ano;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p id="aqui"></p>
  
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: Engraçado que passei um id no td e mesmo assim o querySelector retorna null.